# Return a 404 if trailing slash is entered after file extension

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am using `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html` on static `.html` pages to serve as PHP in `.htaccess` file.

The problem is when someone enters a trailing slash after the `.html` file extension, the URL can extend to anything causing huge number of junk/duplicate pages.

e.g.,
`www.example.com/file.html` would serve the same page as `www.example.com/file.html/file.html` or `www.example.com/file.html/anything-here-bla-bla`

If someone enters `www.example.com/file.html/anything`, for example, I want to redirect to a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution myself. Here is what will do the desired.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+).html/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.shtml [NC,R,L]

This will redirect visitors/googlebot to 404.shtml when a trailing slash is added after the file extension (.html) in this case.

Hope this will help others.